# Что означает двоеточие и почему после unsigned не указан тип данных?

Tags: c++, struct, инициализация

Объясните, пожалуйста, что в этой структуре за объявления такие странные? Что означает двоеточие и почему после `unsigned` не указан тип данных?

```
struct byte {
　unsigned a : 1;
　unsigned b : 1;
　unsigned с : 1;
　unsigned d : 1;
　unsigned e : 1;
　unsigned f : 1;
　unsigned g : 1;
　unsigned h : 1;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unsigned` сам о себе является синонимом `unsigned int`, так же как `long` является синонимом `long int`. Это пережиток [правила "неявного `int`"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_int) из "классического" языка С. Такого правила больше нет ни в С, ни в С++, но его наследие продолжает жить вот в такой форме.

`:` означает, что объявляется битовое поле: поле размером в 1 бит.

Comment: т.е. переменные a,b,c занимают только по 1 биту и могут принимать только 0 или 1?

Comment: @double u: Да, именно так. Имейте в виду, что "плотная упаковка" таких полей не гарантируется языком, но реализации обычно ее выполняют.

Comment: Стоит также упомянуть про выравнивание и pragma once

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch: А `pragma once`-то тут при чем?

Comment: @AnT чтобы гарантировать размер структуры и избежать выравнивания

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Имеете в виду `pragma pack`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ах да, опечатка, хотел написать pragma pack